# Why is there no option to change what closing the lid does on a laptop?

Tags: release-freya, power, laptop

Why is there no option to change what closing the lid does on a laptop? it is really troublesome

Comment: This has since been answered here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/how-to-change-laptop-lid-close-behaviour-to-not-suspend-when-the-lid-is-closed/1758#1758

Answer (score 4):

Long story short, it's not something that could be done technically in Freya. In the next release, with the migration to SystemD, it will be technically possible to implement the feature again.

Comment: Was it implemented in Loki? Doesn't look like it.